# Do we really need four tags about moderation?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, synonym-request

Do we really need [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation), [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools), [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities) and [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators)? From the excerpts:

- [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools): Tools available to ♦ moderators. (862 questions)
- [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation): This tag is for questions dealing with moderator actions, pages, abilities or decisions. (533 questions)
- [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators): Questions about diamond (♦) moderators, their powers, and actions they have taken.  (380 questions)
- [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities): A subset of privileges available to moderators and users with high reputation. (148 questions)

---

It seems that [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) is also for 10k moderators, as it mentiones moderator pages. If so I suggest [moderator-abilities](/questions/tagged/moderator-abilities) as a synonym.

I think that [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) is certainly a subset of [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators), since the latter also mentiones their powers, even though the former has more questions. I suggest this as  a synonym.

We also have [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools).

---

Comment: So what do you propose? Merge some of them ?

Comment: @HackerKarma See the second section for my proposal of two synonyms.

Comment: There is definitely room for improvement here... I also agree with MadScientist's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We need [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools), there is a feed in the moderator chat room that posts all questions with that tag. It' s pretty convenient to notify moderators about meta posts that concern the tools they use.

This should stay a separate tag in any case, it's useful and pretty specific.

Comment: I didn't know that, but we might want to do something with the other three tags.

Comment: @wythagoras why? what does lots of tags do that's bad?